# javascript- uncaught type error has no method

Tags: javascript, object, methods, typeerror

Only the following page, I am getting the following error on a Photo Gallery:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tmpl'
```

http://www.joostrap.com/hints-tips

Any ideas what this is & how I can sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

> The .ready() method is generally incompatible with the  attribute. If load must be used, either do not use .ready()
>   or use jQuery's .load() method to attach load event handlers to the
>   window or to more specific items, like images.

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). You have `window.addEvent('load'...` conflicting with `.ready()`

Comment: Can you advise what I should change please - I'm not a JS guru!

Comment: Use jQuery's `.ready()` or `.load()` instead of `addEvent` as suggested in the documentation